# PHP and HTML issue

Tags: php, html

Good Afternoon Comunity,

Well, the problem is i have a DIV PA on my index.html wich display a login window if you are not connect or a properity window if you are connect

http://imageshack.com/a/img23/3821/m6h0.jpg

The problem is when i use the code, i get this stetic error
http://imageshack.com/a/img812/2720/keg6.jpg

The code works fine except that error

```
<div id="apDiv7">

<?php 
boolean allowed = false;
if (allowed)
{
echo "<br><br><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
     <label for="Usuario"></label>

        <input type="text" name="Usuario" id="Usuario" align="absmiddle" size="23" >
      </form> 
   <form name="form2" method="post" action="">
        <label for="clave"></label>
      <br>
       <input type="password" name="clave" id="clave" size="23">
      </form>   
<div><form name="form3" method="post" action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="casilla" id="casilla">

        Seguir Logeado
        <label for="casilla"></label> 
      <input type="reset" name="Crear" id="Crear" value="Entrar">
      </form> 
</div>
<br>
<div><a href="descargar.php">Problema</a>
</div> 
<div><a href="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/descargar.php">Registrarse</a>
</div>" 

}else{

echo "another code";
}
?>

</div>
```

I apogolize in case i wrote something wrong, my english is not as good as i want
Thank in advance. my regards!

EDITED:
Even more i use an echo for each sentences, tried 1 quote, tried  between html code and nothing.
PS: In my design tab from dreamweaver c6 i dont see this problem like on browser

FINAL edited: most of code you posted are working but for some reason (maybe htaccess issue) my pc  cant make it works...tahnk to all for your time!!

Comment: Check your quotation marks. Every time you use `"`, it closes/re-opens a string.

Comment: There are three html forms on the page and no 'submit'button. You have a 'reset' button but that just clears the fields of form3. How does the data in form1 and forms2 get sent? Also, how does the '$allowed' variable get set to force the login screen to be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `echo`. Close and reopen your `php` code around the `HTML.` Also, your php vars need a dollar sign before them. Try this.

```
<div id="apDiv7">

<?php 
$allowed = false;
if ($allowed){
?>
     <br><br>
     <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
       <label for="Usuario"></label>
       <input type="text" name="Usuario" id="Usuario" align="absmiddle" size="23" >
     </form> 
     <form name="form2" method="post" action="">
        <label for="clave"></label>
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="clave" id="clave" size="23">
     </form>   
     <div>
        <form name="form3" method="post" action="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="casilla" id="casilla">
        Seguir Logeado
        <label for="casilla"></label> 
        <input type="reset" name="Crear" id="Crear" value="Entrar">
        </form> 
      </div>
      <br>
      <div><a href="descargar.php">Problema</a>
      </div> 
      <div><a href="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/descargar.php">Registrarse</a>
      </div>
<?php
}
else{
    echo "another code";
}
?>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of code with output.  Make sure you have `php` enabled in `.htaccess` by adding `AddType application/x-httpd-php php php4 php3 html htm`. The `.htaccess` file should be in the root of your server (same as `index.php`)

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mr mseifert but with this code it is not working if/else...still displaying on screen both code (the form and the echo)

Comment: When the above code is pasted into a new document and run, it will display `another code` and nothing else. Double check what you have done.

Comment: Mr mseifert i did what u told me and paste the above code in a new HTML document but  in my case i am getting the form instead "another code". Are you getting another code? Are u using html document? Sorry for take some of your time!

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot of the code and output in browser. I get the same results whether I use a php extension or html extension. Make sure you have php enabled in `.htaccess` by adding `AddType application/x-httpd-php php php4 php3 html htm`. The `.htaccess` file should be in the root of your server (same as `index.php`).

Comment: i was reading a little and its look like xampp on window is diseable htaccess...ill try to enable and see if i can have success on this.

Comment: installed latest xampp and still cant get "another code" so for sure is something on my pc. Thank for your time, ill try another course, maybe with jquery! Regards

Comment: Have you tried editing / creating `.htaccess` and adding the code I posted above? Even if you use jquery, you'll still want to make sure php is working.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're using double quotation marks (") for everything, so you're opening and closing the string countless times. I'm actually surprised that you're getting what you are, but I'm sure your error file is full.

Try this:

```
div id="apDiv7">

<?php 
boolean allowed = false;
if (allowed)
{
echo '<br><br><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
     <label for="Usuario"></label>

        <input type="text" name="Usuario" id="Usuario" align="absmiddle" size="23" >
      </form> 
   <form name="form2" method="post" action="">
        <label for="clave"></label>
      <br>
       <input type="password" name="clave" id="clave" size="23">
      </form>   
<div><form name="form3" method="post" action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="casilla" id="casilla">

        Seguir Logeado
        <label for="casilla"></label> 
      <input type="reset" name="Crear" id="Crear" value="Entrar">
      </form> 
</div>
<br>
<div><a href="descargar.php">Problema</a>
</div> 
<div><a href="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/descargar.php">Registrarse</a>
</div>';

}else{

echo 'another code';
}
?>

</div>
```

OR, and this is my preferred method when writing HTML inside a PHP file

```
div id="apDiv7">

<?php 
boolean allowed = false;
if (allowed)
{
?>
<br><br><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
     <label for="Usuario"></label>

        <input type="text" name="Usuario" id="Usuario" align="absmiddle" size="23" >
      </form> 
   <form name="form2" method="post" action="">
        <label for="clave"></label>
      <br>
       <input type="password" name="clave" id="clave" size="23">
      </form>   
<div><form name="form3" method="post" action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="casilla" id="casilla">

        Seguir Logeado
        <label for="casilla"></label> 
      <input type="reset" name="Crear" id="Crear" value="Entrar">
      </form> 
</div>
<br>
<div><a href="descargar.php">Problema</a>
</div> 
<div><a href="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/descargar.php">Registrarse</a>
</div>

<?php
}else{
?>

another code

<?php
}
?>

</div>
```

Notice how the HTML isn't inside PHP tags, but it IS inside a PHP if statement. It still works, and you don't have to worry about crossing your PHP and HTML syntax when you do it that way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Mr David, i tried with the first option but still get same problem and the second option dont work if/else because  its displaying on screen both code. Regards

Comment: @user3433247 what is your error log saying? Clear it, reload the file, and see what errors come up.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using double quotes both for echo and for html codes.

Use single quotes on echo, and this will not happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Some code that shows the different parts correctly.

There is now only one form with a 'submit' button.

As there is so little logic i have used 'alternate syntax' for the logic statements.

```
<div id="apDiv7">

<?php
/* debug */ var_dump($_POST); // remove this -- i want to see the input.

$allowed = true; // force the login screen to be shown
?>

<?php if ($allowed): ?>

<br><br><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
     <label for="Usuario">Usuario</label>
     <input type="text" name="Usuario" id="Usuario" align="absmiddle" size="23" >
      <br>
       <label for="clave">clave</label>
      <input type="password" name="clave" id="clave" size="23">
  <div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="casilla" id="casilla">

        Seguir Logeado
        <label for="casilla"></label>
      <input type="submit" name="Crear" id="Crear" value="Entrar">
      </form>
</div>
<br>
<div><a href="descargar.php">Problema</a>
</div>
<div><a href="file:///C|/xampp/htdocs/descargar.php">Registrarse</a>
</div>

<?php else: ?>

another code

<?php endif; ?>

</div>
```